# What community would I use to ask about vehicle titles, Law or Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I have an issue with a used motorcycle that I want to buy, but there are some iffy things about the title that I would like to ask about. What would be the appropriate Stack Exchange site for such a post?

Comment: Depends on what those "iffy" things are - could you provide a little more detail? We don't like to send users off to other sites based on vague criteria that might actually be off-topic there. But believe it or not, your local titling office might be a better place to get questions answered.

Comment: Basically the guy is selling a 2006 Kawasaki Ninja 250 for $1k (suspicious) , and he's saying that the previous owner bought the bike  and the title had a typo in it, so since he couldnt do anything with the bike , he sold it to this guy. This guy is saying the previous owner mailed him the title  but he never got it. So my question would be , can I get a new title for it? What would I even do?

Comment: sounds like you want [Mechanics.se], but they wouldn't go into the law part of it

Comment: @Pacified That does sound like a question for your local titling office, and they can give you all the necessary forms. But you'll also wanna take the VIN with you so it can be checked to make sure it isn't stolen, which is certainly only something the titling office or police could tell you.

Comment: should i do this before or after the purchase is another question..

Comment: I mean, if you're concerned about whether the sale would be legitimate for you, investigating the vehicle as much as possible before buying it is probably a good idea. I can't really think of a good question you could ask on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) where the answer wouldn't just be "go talk to the police or titling office to get better information." The police can tell you if it's stolen, the titling office *might* tell you who it's currently registered to, if at all. Perhaps a good question for Law might be: "Can an owner without the title legally sell a motorcycle, and how?"

Comment: Absolutely before. Receiving stolen property is a crime in many places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask about any technical concerns with the motorcycle on Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. This could be (up to) helping to determine if the VIN plate might have been tampered with, or questions about specific concerns you have with the condition or fitness of the bike.

For the titling stuff, the answer is most resoundingly going to be contact the motor vehicle administration in your area - so that's probably the best place to start. Make sure you see a clear way to getting the bike titled properly before you even *think* about any mechanical concerns the bike might have.

If it looks like you can do the purchase and get a clean title, you can *then* see about concerns surrounding the fitness of the bike.

I'd start at your local MVA and work from there.